# Windows Task Scheduler "Launch request ignored, instance already running"

Tags: windows-server-2012, taskscheduler

I have a task which triggers every 5 min every day. But recently, I found the task always failed between only 8:00 am to 9:00 am but all the other tasks (some trigger every 1 min) do not have any problem. So I have no idea what's wrong.

From log below, I can see there was a trigger at 8:20 and it finally terminated at 8:30. Actually, the task is quite simple to take less than 1 min to finish. So I have no idea why there are "Launch request ignored, instance already running" warnings.

[image: Task Log]

Comment: A server restart worked for me. My task was set to not run a new instance if already running and etc. But a server restart fixed the issue.

Answer (score 32):

It can happen that a task that runs as scheduled task simply does not terminate. Whether this is a fault of task manager or the script is unknown, but both can be at fault here. For example, if the batch file contains a pause statement, the batch file expects a keypress to continue. The task scheduler will never send it, and this the script never finishes.

Try changing few options in task scheduler.
At the bottom of the property window, you will find:

```
'If the task is already running, the following applies" make it "Do start a 
new intstance".

Change this to "Run a new instance in parallel"
```

[image]
This should solve your problem.

Comment: Ironically this worked. Task Scheduler Settings is the baine/pain of my existence sometimes. You follow the "logical" approach with these Settings, but they don't actually work the way you expect. Like common sense would say - yes tick them all and set your timers, etc, but for me it's best to leave them all unticked!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue encounter, so i have come up with the solution that script running on the scheduler opened/accessed by other user on the server, in that case scheduler will not perform any action.

Solution - Logoff all the users connected with the server..

Hopefully this will help